# Terms for duplicated words

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't recall term used for duplicating extraneous words e.g. VIP person (Very Important Person Person), first question what is this term?

Second question, is the same term used when the duplicated term is a synonym?

Comment: this one should have a tag "ras" and/or "redundant-acronym-syndrome". i don't have enough rep to do that.

Comment: @spinodal: or the tag ras-redundant-acronym-syndrome

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's called RAS Syndrome (Redundant Acronym Syndrome Syndrome).

Comment: Lol -- reminds me of TLA (Three Letter Acronym), ETLA (Extended Three Letter Acronym), and EETLA (Expanded Extended Three Letter Acronym)

Comment: And "The TTP Project" (where TTP stands for "The TTP Project") :)

Comment: @Stein G. Strindhaug: good one, I hadn't heard of that. Trying to expand the acronym is a nice exercise in endless-loop recursion.

Comment: @Stein Yeah, and `PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor`. These are called [recursive acronyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym).

Comment: @SteinG.Strindhaug I guess "TTP" can also be considered to be a [recursive acronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym).

Answer (score 3):

I think the word you're looking for is redundant. In the phrase *VIP person*, "person" is **redundant** because it is already implied by VIP. It is not a synonym. A synonym for VIP might be dignitary.