# Is there a word for an acronym which spells out one of its component words?

Tags: acronyms

The example I am thinking of is GNU, which stands for "[GNU's not unix](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~trent/gnu/)".

It may be that there are no other examples. And maybe that's the whole joke. I was just wondering.

Comment: It is also jokingly said that in "Benoît B. Mandelbrot", the "B" stands for "Benoît B. Mandelbrot".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terms for duplicated words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7037/terms-for-duplicated-words)

Comment: Recursive acronym?

Comment: There are plenty of other examples.  One such is "MUNG", which stands for "MUNG until no good".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's usually called a [recursive acronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_acronym). It draws, by its very nature (and geekiness), a certain fondness from computer hobbyists and is thus heavily used in naming software packages, programming concepts or algorithms. There are, however, some non-technical examples (drawn from the Wikipedia page linked above):

- IRIS, for Iris Recognition Immigration System
- Visa, for Visa International Service Association

---

Also of note: “GNU Hurd” is a mutually recursive acronym, where “Hurd” stands for “Hird of Unix-Replacing Daemons”, and “Hird” stands for “Hurd of Interfaces Representing Depth”.

Comment: Strictly speaking, recursive acronyms are only a subset of what the OP asked for. An acronym may spell out a component word without being recursive, as this wildly made-up example proves: NEWS (News editing work space)

Comment: @Simon - the first example that @F'x gave, "IRIS", falls into that same category - it's a database of biometric information, mainly iris scans.

Answer (score 4):

They're called "[recursive acronyms](http://sucs.org/~arthur/jargon/html/entry/recursive-acronym.html)":

> A hackish (and especially MIT)
>   tradition is to choose
>   acronyms/abbreviations that refer
>   humorously to themselves or to other
>   acronyms/abbreviations. The classic
>   examples were two MIT editors called
>   EINE ("EINE Is Not EMACS") and ZWEI
>   ("ZWEI Was EINE Initially"). More
>   recently, there is a Scheme compiler
>   called LIAR (Liar Imitates Apply
>   Recursively), and GNU (q.v., sense 1)
>   stands for "GNU's Not Unix!" -- and a
>   company with the name Cygnus, which
>   expands to "Cygnus, Your GNU Support"
>   (though Cygnus people say this is a
>   backronym).

For more examples, read DR Hofstadter's "*[Gödel, Escher, Bach: an Eternal Golden Braid](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465026567)*" - that's where I first heard of them, and many other wonders of language/math/science/art/computers/music as well.