# A sensible mnemonic for "pseudo"

Tags: mnemonic

Whenever I go to use the pseudo- prefix, I always have to pause for a moment and decide what the correct e-u order is. Often times I get it wrong. Built in typo correction frequently helps, though there are some instances (irssi, ... written forms) where such a feature does not exist.

I'm very interested in a witty/rhythmic/useful mnemonic to help me remember the correct spelling of pseudo- in full, or even something specific to the e-u ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind an acronym that uses RAS syndrome (see [Terms for duplicated words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7037/terms-for-duplicated-words)), you could try

> Pseudo-science ends up dumped out.

Comment: That is amazing. I don't think I've ever heard of RAS syndrome that directly either.

Comment: Oddly enough, I've never successfully remembered this line, but I always remember "Pseudo Science eventually *something* *something* thrown out", yes, "something something" included, which is enough to remind me it starts with Ps*e*.

Answer (score 3):

Practise spelling Europe, usefully done often.

Comment: But Europe is not the same. Plus, what does Europe have to do with pseudo? There's no connection for my brain to draw there. Additionally, pseudo has a strong-u sound (like sue-dough) where Europe has a strong-eu sound (yer-ope).

P.S. I apologize for completely ruining things that are sensible, like the IPA, in this comment.t

Comment: We clearly pronounce things differently; for me (British English) it's syoo-dough and yoo-rup. A tenuous connection is that pseudo is a Greek word (from Europe). Hopefully someone else can come up with a better mnemonic for you!

Comment: I didn't occur to me that your answer would be rooted in British english despite the use of "practise" :). Us American English practicers (bad grammar intention) have a lot of silly changes to those words, I'm sure you're generally aware of many of them.

A friend is telling me that I don't have to have such a logical mnemonic as much as I have to have a point of comparison, so currently I'm running with yours. We'll see how it goes next time I have to spell pseudo-, (and that didn't count :P).

Comment: @VxJason: This is actually a really good tip that actually makes sense. In Greek, *-eu-* is a common diphthong, while *-ue-* is rare. So what if you just remember that all words that come from Greek have *-eu-*, and think of the spelling of Europe when in doubt, which you will surely spell right? // Europe comes from *eurus* = "broad" and *op-* = "view" (the *a* is because Europa was a mythological woman, look it up). *Pseudo-* comes from *pseudomai,* "to tell lies". Another thing to note is that English has hardly any words (perhaps none) that start with *ps-* but do not come from Greek.

Answer (score 2):

My Greek friends sometimes pronounce it psevdo ('p' not silent). Maybe if you learn to associate "pseudo" with *psevdo*, you'll spell it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Popped into my head just now...

"Ewww" is a verbal expression of disgust.

Pseudopods are pretty gross.

A drawn out "eee yoo" sounds like that expression of disgust. "Yoo eee" not so much.

Just an idea.