# "VPN Networks" vs. "VPNs"

Tags: abbreviations, writing-style

I am writing a technical report on a topic which includes a *Virtual Private Network*. These are commonly abbreviated as VPN.

However it feels strange writing something along the lines of

> VPNs are often employed to ...

On the other hand a formulation such as

> VPN networks are often employed to ...

is a pure tautology, as it basically means *Virtual Private Networks Networks*.

As for actually writing

> Virtual Private Networks are often employed to ...

Although this works and is surely correct, it will fill my text with a lot of useless clutter, I can't possibly write out the abbreviation more than once or twice per paragraph.

Comment: Related: [PIN numbers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14868), [ATM machines](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21382), and [VIP persons](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7037/terms-for-duplicated-words).

Comment: Ah, many good answers and quickly too. Thx all of you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Writing "VPNs" is not strange in the least.
2. The Recursive Acronym Syndrome Syndrome [exists for a reason](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/pin-number-why-do-we-say-it), so even "VPN networks" can be perfectly fine depending on how established the acronym *VPN* is in your domain.
3. And of course there's nothing wrong whatsoever with writing "Virtual Private Networks".

I would go with "VPNs". Though it is good practice to expand any acronym the very first time you use it in a text.

Comment: Ah - while you were editing...

Comment: @mplungjan sorry!)))

Comment: Thx for pointing out the RAS syndrome, that was a good read. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would write first time *Virtual Private Networks (VPNs) are...* and then use VPNs in the rest of the text

Comment: This is what we are told to do in my course - exactly as mplungjan has given, with the full term then abbreviations in brackets so that the reader knows what it stands for and the abbreviation, so that they know what it is when they next see it.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three classes of target audience, according to which I would chose one of the three formats.

Intra-domain readers (those belonging to the domain and entirely familiar with it):
*VPNs are often employed to ...*
because they know it and they hate to be told every time what a *VPN* stands for.

Extra-domain technical readers:
*Virtual Private Networks (VPNs)*
at first reference; *VPNs* in all subsequent references.

Non-technical, general or anonymous readers:
*VPNs (Virtual Private Networks)*
at first reference; *VPN networks* in all subsequent references. In this case, the tautology serves to help in hiding the technical detail (type of network) within the abbreviation while reminding the reader what it is (network). This is not incorrect and is in fact used as a convenience technique. (cf. [J.R.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101034/vpn-networks-vs-vpns#comment205074_101034) above.)

In no case is *Virtual Private Networks* used repeatedly in the course of the document.